# zip Cuts off After First Letter

Tags: python, database, csv, dictionary, zip

I'm trying to run the following code:

```
def by_primary_key(table, key, fields) -> object:
    key_columns = get_key_columns(table, key )
    print("key columns in get by primary key " , key_columns)
    print("key, " , key )
    zip_it = list(zip(key_columns, key))
    print("zip_it", zip_it )
    dictt = dict(zip_it)
    print("dict", dictt)
```

The output I want for zip_it is: [('playerID', 'willite01')]

but the output the program produces is:
key columns in get by primary key  ['playerID']

key,  willite01

zip_it [('playerID', 'w')]

dict {'playerID': 'w'}

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The following worked

```
key_columns = get_key_columns(table, key )
lst = []
lst.append(key)
tmp = dict(zip(key_columns, lst))
result = find_by_template1(table, tmp, fields)
return result
```